# Create a Line graph with Dots and Labels using 2 different data sets

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graph, charts

I would like to create a line graph that also has dots with labels on it similar to: [image: this picture] I want to use 2 different data sets though because one of them is coming from an API.

Here are the two data sets:

```
Data set 1
09/01/17, 55.65
09/02/17, 63.88
09/03/17, 57.49
09/04/17, 58.59

Data set 2
09/01/17, 55.65, Label 1 here
09/02/17, 63.88, Label 2 here
09/03/17, 57.49, Label 3 here
09/04/17, 58.59, Label 4 here
```

Here's what I have so far ([from this tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/38744a17f9c0141bcd04)):

```
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
.orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.close = +d.close;
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));

// Add the scatterplot
svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

});

function addLabels(){
    d3.csv("dataset2.csv", function(error, data){
        svg.append('g')
        .classed('labels-group', true)
        .selectAll('text')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .classed('label', true)
        .attr({
        'x': function(d, i) {
                return x(d.date);
            },
            'y': function(d, i) {
                return y(d.data);
            }
        })
        .text(function(d, i) {
            return d.label;
        });
    });
}

addLabels();
```

Question: Can someone help me add labels to this the dots on this graph? Keep in mind I am using two different data sets.

Comment: I'm confused, why are you using 2 identical datasets? Other than the label, why not just use dataset 2. Assuming your dataset 2 is date, value, label, then you just need to access the label using d.label and append the text.

Comment: Yea I may be confused too. Basically I'm graphing the price of a stock on a given day, and then im adding "events" that happened on certain days as dots/labels on the graph to see if there is any correlation between rises/drops in prices and events. Does that make sense? The date and price I'm adding from an API since I don't know what the price was each day in the past, and the events I'm adding manually to show where they occurred along the line. I'm not sure if this requires two separate data sets, but it seems like it would since the price info is populated dynamically

Comment: nice hand drawing, you can do that, by draw line chart first, and select that line chart and draw dot using same, x scale

Comment: OK, so dataset1 is stock price that comes in automatically, then you add the  labels to a second data set that you've copied and edited yourself. I have an idea...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like your current function is creating the scatterplot from dataset1, what I'd do is add a second, entirely separate function for the labels:

```
function addLabels(){
d3.csv("dataset2.csv", function(error, data2){
svg.append('g')
.classed('labels-group', true)
.selectAll('text')
.data(data2)//this should have been data2, to reflect data coming from the second request.
.enter()
.append('text')
.classed('label', true)
.attr({
'x': function(d, i) {
return x(d.date);
},
'y': function(d, i) {
return y(d.data);
 }
})
.text(function(d, i) {
return d.label;
});
}
}
```

then call this function from the end of the function that draws the line (if it starts to slow things down, use a timer to allow the rest of the data to plot first).
Credit to [this other user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589401/d3-add-data-value-labels-to-multi-line-graph) for the labels code. It's what I was thinking, but neater.

Edit: I forgot to change the dataset being used, see comment above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this and there are no errors but the labels are not populating. Here's what I'm using for dataset 2: 27-Aug-12,"label 1",
28-Aug-12,"label 2". I'm using your code and calling addLabels() but the labels are not displaying. No errors in console. Any ideas?

Comment: labels-group is populating with nothing inside it it seems.

Comment: do you have a working demo by chance? - I'm getting NaN error

Comment: Hmm, I'm more of a tooltip user, this is from the other question I linked, http://plnkr.co/edit/lDlseqUQQXgoFwTK5Aop?p=preview which has the labels, but they probably need raising off the line. Have you got a column header in your csv file (label), it would be easier to see your example. Can you see the labels in the data (console.log(data2)).